# insert a line break with a specific value of a file

Tags: python, file

I want to search in a file with a specific value and give a line break and write in the existing file and a separate file

**Source Code**

```
input_file= "test.txt"
putput_file="result.txt"
def search_break(input_file):
    with open(input_file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print lines
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if i == "Foo":
                print
        print lines[i]
            if i== "50.000"
                print
        print lines[i]

            f.close()



print search_break(input_file)
```

**Input File**-test.txt

```
50.000
0.6016
1.0000
Foo
0.7318
1.0000
```

**Output File**-test.txt

```
50.000
0.6016
1.0000

Foo
0.7318
1.0000
```

**Output File**-result.txt

```
50.000
0.6016
1.0000

Foo
0.7318
1.0000
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines` keeps newline characters, so you need to strip them off before testing, otherwise it'll never match. I also combined all search words into one `set`, and simplified the loop:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().lower() in {"foo", "50.000"}:  # added .lower() and changed match strings to lowercase
            print
        print line,   # added comma to prevent the automatic newline
```

Using multiple `if..else` statements:

```
with open(input_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "Foo":
            print
        elif line.strip() == "50.000":
            print
        print line,   # added comma to prevent the automatic newline
```

Comment: It gives break in every single line.

Comment: Can you please show switch case or if else example ?

Comment: I wanted to see the Switch case example for learning purpose. Yes it is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: switch case meaning you want it to be case insensitive? python doesn't have the switch case syntax other languages do, just if..else. I've updated my answer with that, if it's what you meant

Comment: @Raid, for what it's worth, i modified the answer once more with a `.lower()` comparison against a lowercase `set`, if it helps